# core_enable_profiling wcf behavior extensions

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

I have two extensions in a WCF services web.config file. If I set the environment variable .net core_enable_profiling to 1 (on) the CLR immediately complains about the behavior extensions being referenced in the service behavior section complaining about "object reference not set to an instance of an object". If the core_enable_profiling variable is set to 0 (off) everything runs perfectly. If we remove the behavior extension references the the WCF services run fine (but our client application breaks because it uses the extensions). All of the configuration is perfectly defined based on the MS standards.

1. Has anyone else encountered this?
2. Is it the case that profiling in .NET is not compatible with WCF behavior extension definitions?